# TPU 3d printed texture

Tags: rendering, texturing, photorealism

New to blender, I try to make a realistic 3D printed TPU plastic texture, but the result is not that good... I would also be super nice to have the layering...

[image: Texture]
[image: Shading]

Thank you for your advises !

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing and decided to make a TPU material myself. I did it using a brick texture with the row height set really high, brick width set low, and mortar thickness very low to create tightly spaced long thin vertical line and feeding that into the Normal socket. You could experiment with mixing the Brick Texture with a Noise Texture to give it some more randomness, or by feeding the brick texture into the Color socket, varying the brick colors and changing the Brick Texture Bias setting to give it more color variance between the lines.

[image: Preview of 3D printed TPU material]

[image: Node Setup]

[image: Real 3d printed TPU]